# Bootstrap column not filling up grid if I add margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to loop a number of `div` with a class of `col-sm-3`, technically it should loop 4 divs in a row. Technically, it does, but whenever I add just a margin, even just 1px, i automatically puts the last column below. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHdSk.jpg), and this is what it looks like [without a margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un8N2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, the margin will be added to the 25% so the total is more than 100%. I suggest you to use padding instead. You need to had some div inside the `col-sm-3` and put the `background : #fff` on them.